# What is wrong with my SQLiteDataAdapter.UpdateCommand?

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

I've tried it here, and it isn't working.  The Tournament name returns null, and champion+runnerup revert back to their original values..  What am i doing wrong?

Here is a record in DB Browser before editing in the datagridview(datagridview is bound to datasetx):

[image]

```
adapter.UpdateCommand = new SQLiteCommand(
   "UPDATE SmashTournaments SET TournamentName = @TournamentName, Champion = (SELECT R1.SmashRosterID 
    FROM SmashRoster R1 WHERE CharacterName = @Champion)," +
                "RunnerUp = (SELECT R2.SmashRosterID FROM SmashRoster R2 WHERE CharacterName = @RunnerUp) WHERE TournamentID = @TournamentID", cnn);
adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(
    "@TournamentName", DbType.String, 50, "TournamentName");
adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(
    "@Champion", DbType.String, 50, "Champion");
adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(
    "@RunnerUp", DbType.String, 50, "RunnerUp");
adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(
    "@TournamentID", DbType.Int64, 3, "TournamentID");

adapter.Update(dataSetx);
```

And here is that same record after editing all fields in the datagridview and clicking button1(I typed in name1, Tst5, Tst6, which should have updated the table to show name1, 5, 6):
[image]

I stated earlier that RunnerUp's value does not change.  RunnerUp's value does NOT change if both Champion and RunnerUp are changed.  If Champion is not changed, RunnerUp instead turns into null.

If you click the button without changing any values, nothing happens.

Comment: BTW, the update command does not contain a where clause (in the main statement... I'm not talking about subqueries), so each execution would update every existing row.  You need to specify a primary key match in the where clause.

Comment: You are setting the `SourceVersion` to the `Original` value!  This is precisely why the values are "reverting" back to the original value, because you are setting the parameters to pull the original value from the dataSetx fields.  Just leave the SourceVersion at its default value of `DataRowVersion.Current`.

Comment: @CPerkins Thank you. I have updated the question title and body, removing the SourceVersion change did not effect anything unfortunately, the result is still the same.

Comment: Okay, what do you mean by 'Tournament name returns null`?  Does this mean that you query the database afterward (using other code or other tool) and it is now null, but previously was not null?  Even better would be to include sample data... show a database row before and after the code is executed.  Indicate precisely what changed... like "editing the value in a gridview control bound to the dataSetx, then the code shown is executed.  I then reviewed the table in DB Browser to inspect the updated rows...".  The point is to explain what's going on,  otherwise much of it is guesswork.

Comment: `adapter.Update(dataSetx);` returns the number of rows successfully updated.

Comment: @CPerkins, I have updated the question, showing what the database shows before and after editing, thank you.

Comment: @LarsTech, So the command i'm using isnt the right command at all? Which command am i supposed to use then, to write changes back to the DB? It's updating somehow, because some things are being written back as null..

Comment: There are too many details not present here that are involved in updating the rows, like the data in the related tables, the initialization of the DataAdapter, definition and configuration of the DataSet, binding of the dataview columns to the proper DataSet columns, etc.  All of those details are involved and should be inspected.  Check spellings, order of columns, mappings between DB table and dataset and gridview, etc.  It may be too much to post here, but should be verified.